# Что значит присвоение срезу?

Tags: python

Я рассматриваю реализацию класса `collections.UserList` и увидел там необычный синтаксис:

```
def __init__(self, initlist=None):
        self.data = []
        if initlist is not None:
            # XXX should this accept an arbitrary sequence?
            if type(initlist) == type(self.data):
                self.data[:] = initlist
            elif isinstance(initlist, UserList):
                self.data[:] = initlist.data[:]
            else:
                self.data = list(initlist)
```

Что значит эта строка?
`self.data[:] = initlist.data[:]`
Я предполагаю, что это создание поверхностной копии списка, но почему именно таким образом? Почему бы не написать просто `self.data = initlist.data[:]`? Имеет ли подобный синтаксис какой-нибудь эффект о котором я не знаю?

Comment: Код странный. В первых двух ветках мы сохраняем объект `self.data`, в третьей - стираем. Более того он уже стёрт в начале функции. Зачем `[:]` в `initlist.data[:]`? Это лишнее копирование. Другими словами, если убрать все кроме одной `[:]` из кода, ничего не изменится, только лучше станет. Оставить нужно тут: `self.data[:] = initlist`. Это код копирует данные чтобы избежать лишней связности по данным. И то, я бы написал `self.data = initlist[:]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это сделано для сохранения исходного типа `self.data` как `list` - конструкция `self.data[:] = initlist.data[:]` сохраняет тип контейнера, меняя в нем только содержимое (элементы):

```
import collections

def print_addr(x: list, name:str):
    print(name,id(x), type(x), end=': ')
    for i in x:
        print(id(i), end=', ')
    print()


lst = collections.UserList([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

lst1 = list() # задаем исходный тип явно - list
lst1 = lst

lst2 = list() # задаем исходный тип явно - list
lst2 = lst[:]

lst3 = list() # задаем исходный тип явно - list
lst3[:] = lst[:]

print_addr(lst, 'lst')
print_addr(lst1,'lst1')
print_addr(lst2,'lst2')
print_addr(lst3,'lst3')
```

```
lst 2125914383376 <class 'collections.UserList'>: 140705164223272, 140705164223304, 140705164223336, 140705164223368, 140705164223400, 
lst1 2125914383376 <class 'collections.UserList'>: 140705164223272, 140705164223304, 140705164223336, 140705164223368, 140705164223400, 
lst2 2125990328272 <class 'collections.UserList'>: 140705164223272, 140705164223304, 140705164223336, 140705164223368, 140705164223400, 
lst3 2125914818944 <class 'list'>: 140705164223272, 140705164223304, 140705164223336, 140705164223368, 140705164223400,
```

Как видно из результата, только переменная `lst3` остается `list`

Comment: И конструкция `self.data[:] = initlist.data` делает тоже самое.

Answer (score 5):

Да, вы правы, эта строка создает поверхностную копию списка. Однако, использование синтаксиса `self.data[:]` вместо `self.data = initlist.data[:]` имеет свои преимущества. Когда мы присваиваем `self.data = initlist.data[:]`, мы создаем новый объект списка и присваиваем его переменной `self.data`. Это означает, что если у нас есть другие ссылки на исходный список `initlist`, то они не будут обновлены при изменении `self.data`.

С другой стороны, когда мы используем синтаксис `self.data[:]`, мы обращаемся к существующему объекту списка `self.data` и обновляем его значениями из `initlist.data`. Это означает, что все ссылки на `self.data` будут указывать на обновленный список.

Comment: Обратите внимание что `self.data` меняет `id` выше по коду. Рассуждение про ссылки верное, но не применимое к этому коду.